# vanilla javascript: change parent element into input

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to open this parent element up for editing when the edit button is clicked. My idea was to insert a new input box with the previous text as placeholder. Here is where I'm at:

```
const edit = document.createElement("button")
const newInput = document.createElement("input")
edit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {e.target.parentElement=newInput})
```

Comment: Could you please add some more details?